# Difference between frontier and boundary points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am confused,   in some books ,definitions of boundary point and frontier point is same  .But some of my friends says  both are different  .  Please explain by examples  .

And    also closure of a set A  is union of A and it's limit points .  But is there any counter example    which can disprove   that closure of A is not union of A and it's boundary point .

At this time  according to me  "a point p is boundary point of A if   every neighbourhood of p contains point of A and complement of A "(may be this definition  is wrong )

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of boundary point is correct, and following that definition, the claim

> For every set $A$, the closure of $A$ is the union of $A$ and the boundary of $A$

is true and therefore has no counterexample.

---

As far as the term **frontier** goes, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) explains

> However, frontier sometimes refers to a different set, which is the set of boundary points which are not actually in the set; that is, $\overline S\setminus S$.

So, there are two different uses of the terms, and you just have to be careful to know which one is used in a given context. And if you are writing, when using the terms, always define them first.

Comment: Can you explain this difference of frontier  and boundary point  by examples ? Suppose that frontier points are different .then can you have any example of a point which is boundary point but not frontier Or a point which is frontier  but not boundary point

Comment: @guronkar The boundary of a closed ball is a circle, the frontier of a closed ball is empty.

Comment: Any frontier point is a boundary point, but not conversely, if you follow this definition

Comment: Variations abound. In E. T. Copson's *Metric Spaces* (Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics 57), the term *frontier* of $A$ means what we normally think of as the boundary of $A$, and the term *boundary* of $A$ means the portion of the frontier of $A$ that lies in $A$. So in that terminology, if $A$ is closed then its frontier is its boundary. Yikes.